# Perforce to ignore revision during integrations

Tags: perforce

I have created feature branch for one of our projects, and deleted all documentation files there in one changelist. (I know, bad idea).

I want to integrate back everything except given changelist, I tried following to ignore it:

```
p4 integrate //branch/...@CL,CL //main/...
p4 resolve -at //main/...
```

However, the files still remain marked for deletion - the resolve ends with

```
//main/... - no file(s) to resolver.
```

Is there any way how to tell perforce that given CL is already integrated and ignore it in subsequent integrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you need at least a 2011.1 server to do this (if your server is older you'll get an error message on the integrate):

```
p4 integrate -Rd //branch/...@CL,CL //main/...
p4 resolve -ay
```

The "-R**d**" flag says that files which would normally be opened for **d**elete automatically should be opened for integrate and scheduled for resolve instead.  In turn, the "p4 resolve -a**y**" will say that you want to keep what's in **y**our workspace (an "integrate" with no content change) and submit that as the final result.

The submitted "integrate" revisions will record that you have done this integration (the history will show an "ignore" of the deleted revisions in your branch), but without actually changing the contents of the submitted files.

If you use the "p4 merge" command instead of the "p4 integrate" command (with a more current server version, I think 2013.1 or thereabouts), all files are scheduled for resolve automatically (i.e. including those that would previously have been automatically opened for branch or delete), so with "p4 merge" you always must resolve (and may optionally ignore) any source change.

Relevant p4 blog entries:

- http://www.perforce.com/blog/110620/ignoring-branches-deletes
- http://www.perforce.com/blog/130812/resolve-face-adversity

Comment: I'm not sure why I missed the `-Rd` flag. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you wanted 'resolve -ay' here, not 'resolve -at'. When integrating back to main, I think that "theirs" is the branch, while "yours" is main.

From 'p4 help resolve':

```
   The resolve process is a classic three-way merge. The participating
   files are referred to as follows:

     'yours'       The target file open in the client workspace
     'theirs'      The source file in the depot
     'base'        The common ancestor; the highest revision of the
                   source file already accounted for in the target.
     'merged'      The merged result.

   Filenames, filetypes, and text file content can be resolved by
   accepting 'yours', 'theirs', or 'merged'.  Branching, deletion, and
   binary file content can be resolved by accepting either 'yours' or
   'theirs'.
```

Comment: Bryan, thanks for the answer. I've updated my original question - resolving doesn't do anything (-ay/-at - no change)